# Change Value in JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON:

```
{
"Sonos": [
    {
      "192.168.10.214": [
        {
          "Volume": "5",
          "Extension": null,
          "Name": "Wohnzimmer"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "192.168.10.204": [
        {
          "Volume": "5",
          "Extension": null,
          "Name": "Büro"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

On click I want to change the Volume, I try to do it with this snippet:

```
string[] address = ip.Text.Split(new string[] {" | "}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //ip is a ListViewItem
...
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(config);
jsonObj["Sonos"][address[0]]["Volume"] = "10";
```

Now the last line throws

> Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "192.168.10.214". Int32 array index expected.

How would I update the Volume for the specified IP? I am `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Any hint appreciated!

**EDIT**

Full function as per request:

```
private void IncomingCall()
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (ListViewItem ip in sonosListExt1.Items)
            {
                string[] address = ip.Text.Split(new string[] {" | "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                /* Get current Volume and save */
                string getVol = sendXML("/MediaRenderer/RenderingControl/Control", "GetVolume",
                    "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1",
                    "<InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Channel>Master</Channel>", address[0]);

                XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
                xmlResponse.LoadXml(getVol);
                var curVol = ((XmlElement) xmlResponse.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild).InnerText;

                string config = File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cfg\\config.json");
                dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(config);
                jsonObj["Sonos"][i][address[0]][i]["Volume"] = curVol;
                string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cfg\\config.json", output);

                /* Lower Volume */
                sendXML("/MediaRenderer/RenderingControl/Control", "SetVolume",
                    "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1",
                    "<InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Channel>Master</Channel><DesiredVolume>2</DesiredVolume>", address[0]);

                /* Var up */
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you not deserialize to an object and change the property value of `Volume` for the `IP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Sonos"` is an array as are the subitems and their values.

So access as follows:

```
jsonObj["Sonos"][0][address[0]][0]["Volume"] = "10";
```

**Edit:**

For the `foreach` iteration, consider something similar to this (hacky but if the structure is guaranteed then this should work *shrug*):

```
foreach (ListViewItem ip in sonosListExt1.Items)
{
    var index = sonosListExt1.Items.ToList().IndexOf(ip);
    string[] address = ip.Text.Split(new string[] {" | "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

   /* --- Excluded XML manipulation code --- */

   jsonObj["Sonos"][index][address[0]][0]["Volume"] = "10";  
}
```

Ideally you should change `Sonos` to be a JSON Dictionary with the address values as the key.

Comment: That changes the Volume for the first one, but throws a `Null-Pointer Exception` for the second iteration?

Comment: It would. I've edited to show how you could solve the iteration issue.

Comment: I belive `jsonObj["Sonos"][index][address[index]][0]["Volume"] = "10";  ` should be `jsonObj["Sonos"][index][address[0]][index]["Volume"] = "10";  `, but that does not work either, here the full function http://pastebin.com/ciqs5DGq

Comment: Can't view pastebin currently - better to edit your question and include the whole code.

Comment: You will always reference the first address item with `address[0]`. Is this what you want?

Comment: address[0] is the result of `string[] address = ip.Text.Split(new string[] {" | "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` so yes that is what I want, as it changes every `foreach`

Comment: I assumed you were iterating over/needed to iterate over `address[]`. I've updated the answer again.

Comment: Perfect now, can't believe I didnt find that myself!

Comment: Sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes. ;)